# Are spin and charge related?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, charge, quantum-spin

In Gillan, M.J., 1997. The virtual matter laboratory. Contemporary physics, 38(2), pp.115-130, the author mentions that the repulsive energy between two electrons $1\: \unicode{x212B}$ apart is roughly $14$ eV. Two electrons with opposite spins can have the same set of other quantum numbers, i.e. they could occupy an almost equivalent energy state. Does this mean having opposite spins negates the repulsion to an extent?

I guess the answer might have something to do with the wave nature of electrons but I'm not sure what. Please help me understand this intuitively.

Answer (score 3):

No, these two interaction energies have different order of magnitudes. While the interaction due to the charges is given by Coulomb's law, and therefore the energy is given by
$$
E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{e^2}{r} \approx 14eV
$$
if $r\approx 0.1nm$, the dipole-dipole interaction energy is given by
$$
U_{dd} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \mu^2 \frac{1 - 3\cos^2(\alpha)}{r^3}  \approx 0.5meV
$$
if we use $\mu = 2\mu_{Bohr}$. Hence, the electric interaction energy is approx. $28\, 000$ times stronger.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Semoi. I don't have a strong background in physics. I couldn't relate dipole-dipole interaction with spin. Can you please elaborate on it?

Comment: The spin gives rise to a so called magnetic moment $\mu$. The formula I used is the one for the **magnetic** dipole dipole interaction, which is the interaction between two magnetic moments $\vec \mu_1$ and  $\vec \mu_2$.

Comment: Ah, understood. How then does this dd interaction overcome the electronic repulsion to allow two electrons with opposite spins to occupy an almost similar energy level? (Pardon me if my questions sound short-sighted.)

Comment: I think you are mistaking repulsion between electrons for something called the "Pauli Exclusion Principle"

Comment: @HitanshuSachania: It seams to me as if you are omitting the dominant term: The electric interaction with the positively charged nucleus. E.g. if we consider an Helium atom, we have two electrons and two protons. It is certainly not wise to try to describe an atom classically (instead of qm). However, whatever you do, keep in mind that two electrons will not form a bound-state. The nucleus is crucial.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the repulsion between two electrons is affected by spin or rather by Pauli exclusion. As the electrons are indistinguishable fermions their two particle wave function must be antisymmetric under exchange of the two particles because of the Pauli exclusion principle. As a consequence their repulsion is J-K for the triplet state, for which the sound are parallel and J+K for the singlet state for which spins are antiparallel. J is the ordinary Coulomb repulsion. K is the exchange interaction which is smaller than J. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction

As to the wholly different question in your title, there is no connection between spin and charge. Photons and neutrino's have spin but no charge.